# How can I allow robots access to my sitemap, but prevent casual users from accessing it?

Tags: security, apache, lamp, sitemap

I am storing my sitemaps in my web folder. I want web crawlers (Googlebot etc) to be able to access the file, but I don't necessarily want all and sundry to have access to it.

For example, this site (superuser.com), has a site index - as specified by its *robots.txt* file (https://superuser.com/robots.txt).

However, when you type https://superuser.com/sitemap.xml, you are directed to a 404 page.

How can I implement the same thing on my website?

I am running a LAMP website, also I am using a sitemap index file (so I have multiple site maps for the site). I would like to use the same mechanism to make them unavailable via a browser, as described above.

Answer (score 4):

The best approach will most likely involve getting the IP address of the visitor to the page, performing a reverse NS lookup, and checking if the domain name matches the known list of web crawlers. As far as I know, this is pretty much foolproof (discounting DNS spoofing which is unlikely to be a major problem).

For the Google web crawler, this is described in the blog post [How to verify Googlebot](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2006/09/how-to-verify-googlebot.html).

Here's a list of the domain name wildcards for the most common spider bots/web crawlers:

- Google (Googlebot): *.googlebot.com
- Bing (msnbot): (Not resovable, see [IP ranges](http://chceme.info/ips/))
- Yahoo (Yahoo Slurp): *.yahoo.com

Though I'm not sure how often the IP address ranges for the various main crawlers, there's also [this page](http://chceme.info/ips/) which lists such ranges for the three main search engines.

(Note: I believe the bots do set the user-agent HTTP header on requests, but this is very easy to fake of course.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @noldorin: +1 for the useful links. I am quite new to all this. I think I will like to set up Apache to take into account the information you have provided. Off the top of my head, I think its the <File> or <FileMatch> directives along with 'Allow from'  that I need to set Apache up. But I'm not sure how to 'wire' it all up. Could you please provide a snippet of the section I need to add to my httpd.conf. This will help me get started. Thanks

Comment: @morpheous: Sure, glad to help... Unfortunately I'm no real expert with regards to Apache and HTTP servers. You might want to ask that as a separate question over on ServerFault.com. :)

Comment: +1 for the fact users can't spoof the IP... if you'd suggested user-agent, that would have been an easy hack for any hacker.

Comment: "performing a reverse NS lookup" - Also very easy to fake. It's a better idea to cross-reference the autonomous system which the IP belongs to (and, if you cache that lookup, don't cache it for more than a day or two)

Comment: some (most? all?) of those spiders will cache copies of the pages in question and provide those cached copies to visitors who request them.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide your sitemap files from normal visitors by:

- Naming the sitemap file something obscure that can't be guessed:  *sitemap-jk4KnDJ8.xml*
- **NOT** listing the sitemap file location in *robots.txt*
- Submitting the sitemap to the search engines that you want to fetch it through their web sites.  For example through Google Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 2):

This topic is over 9 years old, but maybe it helps someone right now.

Google itself wrote the following about verifying GoogleBot and other Google crawlers in their [Google Search Central Documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/verifying-googlebot#use-automatic-solutions):

> Alternatively, you can identify Googlebot by IP address by matching the crawler's IP address to the [list of Googlebot IP addresses](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/ipranges/googlebot.json).
>
> For all other Google crawlers, match the crawler's IP address against the [complete list of Google IP addresses](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json).